# How to disable window controls when a modal dialog box is active in TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter, modal-dialog

I am writing a Python application with TkInter. At some point the application (`root`) displays a dialog box (`dlg`, which is a `Toplevel`). In order to make the dialog modal I use the following code:

```
dlg.focus_set()
dlg.grab_set()
dlg.transient(root)
root.wait_window(dlg)
```

This indeed cancels "custom" events outside the dialog box (like the widgets in the main application window), but it does NOT cancel the window manager events, so that for example clicking on the main application window has it regain focus and it can be moved, resized - and even closed! - while the "modal" dialog is still open.

How can I make my dialog truly modal, so that window manager events for the main application window are also suspended while the dialog box is active?

I am using Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Do you _really_ want to disable interactions with the window manager? Instead of disabling it, usually the better answer is to simply be prepared to handle it. For example, closing the dialog window should just do the same thing as  clicking "cancel" (assuming you have a cancel button in the dialog). After all, if the user really wants to close the window they should be allowed to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Bryan. Please note I don't mean to disable the window manager for the dialog box, but for the _main_ application window. What I'm describing is exactly the standard behavior; the user shoud be allowed to close the dialog box - but not the whole application while the dialog is still active.

Comment: why shouldn't the user be allowed to close the whole application? What's wrong with letting them do that, if that's what they want to do?

Comment: We can discuss that, @Bryan, but that's not the issue at hand. This is standard behavior, I didn't invent this. When a dialog is open, the rest of the application is "paralyzed" - and that includes window controls. Whether it makes sense or not, it's the standard, and that's what I want. (As only one use case, imagine a "Do you want to save before quitting?" dialog upon exiting. It doesn't make sense that the user be able to try exiting again while this dialog is open, right?)

Answer (score 0):

you can use root.grab_set_global() as in this exemple:

```
import Tkinter
class Application(Tkinter.Frame):
    def mygrab(self):
        print "grab is ok"
        root.grab_set_global()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Tkinter.Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})
        self.grab = Tkinter.Button(self)
        self.grab["text"] = "Grab",
        self.grab["command"] = self.mygrab
        self.grab.pack({"side": "left"})        

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()`
```

Comment: grab_set_global causes the entire computer to freeze (I don't understand how the OS even allows that). That's definitely NOT the answer!

Comment: After the answer was edited: I specifically mentioned I'm on Python 3; your code is Python 2. Also, grab_set_global "grabs" the entire system, not just within the application. That's NOT what I want (and I still don't understand how the OS even allows that).

Comment: I've added an example. In a modal dialog, usually every interactions outside the dialog box are disabled. if you want to disable the window manager you have no other solution than that but other windows interactions are also disabled until you quit the dialog window.

Comment: that's not the solution I'm after, as there's no way I'm gonna paralyze the whole system. Again, I don't understand why that's even an option. Basically what you're saying is what I want can't be done - can you refer to some source?

Comment: On Unix and ubuntu, there is the O'Reilly documentation of the XwindowSystem. My answer concerns only Unix, not Windows. On Unix, you can probably find it in the doc about the window-manager. On some applications one can remove the window-manager and there are no title-bar and no borders; it's not possible with windows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @bilbo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
dlg.focus_set()
dlg.grab_set()
dlg.transient(root)
dlg.wait_window(dlg)
```

Comment: @Tom You're right, it works on windows but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, @guillegiraldo. I wonder if that's a bug and/or if there are known workarounds.