# Creating a modal dialog box in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog, modal-dialog, python-2.x

*This question is not a duplicate: see below.*

I want to create a modal dialog box in tkinter. In other words, a dialog box which, while it is active, prevents the user from interacting with the parent window. There is [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16803686/how-to-create-a-modal-dialog-in-tkinter) on SO answering this, and there is a [full example](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) illustrating the concept.

However, making the dialog box a Toplevel and calling grab_set() on it simply doesn't work, on either Windows 7 or Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. The user is still able to close, resize, and in general interact with the parent window.

Is there a way of creating a modal dialog box in Tkinter that actually works?

Here is a minimal usage example of dialog.grab_set() failing to prevent interaction with the parent window:

```
import os
try:
    import Tkinter as tkinter
except ImportError:
    import tkinter

class MyToplevel(tkinter.Toplevel, object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.title("Main window")
        MyDialog(self)

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", parent.destroy)

class MyDialog(tkinter.Toplevel, object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.transient(parent)
        self.title("Dialog")
        self.grab_set()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    app = MyToplevel(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

I should point out that using grab_set_global() (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892015/how-to-disable-window-controls-when-a-modal-dialog-box-is-active-in-tkinter)) does work, but is not a viable solution because it blocks access to all windows, for the entire system.

Comment: Hmmm...
That's weird because when trying to reproduce your bug, I can't resize nor use the Main Window. I use Windows 10, may it be a OS related problem ? Did you tried using your small piece of code on both WIndows and Linux ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7; have updated the main post with that info.

Comment: I also tried on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with the same results.

Comment: Wow ! That's super weird...

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: This is a python version problem. I can reproduce this behaviour on _python2.7_ but not on _python3.7_

Comment: On Ubuntu, I tried Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2. On Windows, I will check the version used later.

Comment: On Windows 7 using Python 2.7.14 it works OK for me.

Comment: I can confirm that upgrading to Python 2.7.15 and any of a number of recent releases Python 3 fixes the issue on Windows. I'm not sure how to fix it on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is (at least on windows) a version specific problem. To make it work on `python2.7`, just add `self.focus_force()` before `self.grab_set()`:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    tkinter.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)

    self.transient(parent)
    self.title("Dialog")

    self.focus_force() # added
    self.grab_set()

    self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
```

Comment: I can confirm that updating to newer versions of Python 2.7 and 3 fixes the problem on Windows. (With 2.7, specifically 2.7.15, I didn't need to use self.focus_force(), although it's a good idea to use it.) However, upgrading to the latest version of Python doesn't fix the problem on Ubuntu.